# number formatting 9'999.00

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I'd like to format a number in a SQL select like this

```
9'999'999.00
```

How can I do this?

It works for `9,999,999` with the following command

```
to_char(9999999, 'FM9G999G999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just replace group separator (`.`) with a single quote (`'`) and you are good to go.

```
select to_char(9999999, 'FM9G999G999D00', 
               q'[NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.'']') as res
  from dual
```

result:

```
RES          
-------------
9'999'999.00 

1 row selected.
```